# How to model multiple table "inheritance" in Postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema

I'm trying to model a few different use cases that require "inheritance" in my Postgres database, and realizing there are multiple ways to do it and I'm not sure which is best.

The two specific use cases I'm thinking of are:

- "Memberships" — where a single "user" can be a member of different types of objects: "teams", "collections" or "items". In this case, the membership types are capped at those three types of relationships. (For now.)
- "Events" — where an "event" can be created relating to any other of the objects in my data model—eg. "teams.create", "users.update", "webhooks.create", "items.publish", etc. In this case, the "types" of relationships aren't really capped because whenever I add a new data model, there's a good chance I'll want to allow events to be created for it.

Here are a few of the ways I could see implementing these needs...

(Using the "Memberships" use case for these code snippets, but the same thing applies to the "Events" use case too.)

---

### 1. XOR Columns

```
CREATE TABLE memberships (
  id TEXT,
  user_id TEXT,
  team_id TEXT,
  collection_id TEXT,
  item_id TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (collection_id) REFERENCES collections (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items (id),
  CHECK (
    (team_id IS NOT NULL)::integer + 
    (collection_id IS NOT NULL)::integer +
    (item_id IS NOT NULL)::integer = 1
  )
);
```

**Pros:**

- The database handles the foreign relationships for you.
- Writing `JOIN`s is less verbose.

**Cons:**

- There are extra `NULL` column values for every row.
- The `CHECK` constraint is a bit weird?
- New "types" require adding a `*_id` column and changing the `CHECK`.

---

### 2. Pair of Columns

```
CREATE TABLE memberships (
  id TEXT,
  user_id TEXT,
  target_type TEXT,
  target_id TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
  CHECK (target_type IN ('team', 'collection', 'items'))
);
```

**Pros:**

- Adding new "type" doesn't require adding a column.
- Each row doesn't have extra `NULL` column values.
- You don't need a constraint to ensure only one target exists per row.

**Cons:**

- You have to guarantee data consistency in the application layer.
- Writing `JOIN` queries is a bit more verbose.
- You have to change the `CHECK` constraint when adding new "types".

---

### 3. Many Tables

```
CREATE TABLE team_memberships (
  id TEXT,
  user_id TEXT,
  team_id TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams (id)
);

CREATE TABLE collection_memberships (
  id TEXT,
  user_id TEXT,
  collection_id TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (collection_id) REFERENCES collections (id)
);

CREATE TABLE item_memberships (
  id TEXT,
  user_id TEXT,
  item_id TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items (id)
);
```

**Pros:**

- The database handles foreign key relationships for you.
- There are no extra `NULL` column values in any rows.

**Cons:**

- You end up creating a lot of tables, one for each relationship type.

---

The **Pair of Columns** approach seems widespread, but it means that the database is no longer handling the foreign key relationships for you automatically, which seems like a pretty big downside—things like `CASCADE` are no longer an option. To me this seems like it is too big of a negative to make it a legitimate option.

The **Many Tables** approach also seems widespread, and for the "Memberships" use case it makes sense. But for other use cases like "Events" (where an event could be created relating to any object in your database, not a pre-constrained list), then it seems unwieldy to have such a large amount of tables.

The **XOR Columns** approach doesn't seem as widespread, or at least I couldn't find as much information about it, but it feels like a nice balance, that still lets the database do all of the work, without adding lots of tables.

Are there any glaring problems with the **XOR Columns** approach?

Is there a recommended way to solve this?

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag since your question seems to be for Postgres.

Comment: To advocate **Pair of Columns** approach, I'd say, you can still implement foreign key restrictions in triggers manually, if you want.

Comment: This is an opinion based question, but I feel different from @AlexM: I'd go for **XOR Columns** or **Many Tables**, with a slight preference of the latter. The downsides seem harmless, and the key argument is that queries will be simpler, which will be good for your application.